# Javafx hide Listcell

Tags: listview, javafx, hide

I have a Listview of AnchorPanes with Imageviews inside and want to hide them under special circumstances. In a first step tried wheather I am able to 
 hide them at all. As you can see, I tried all posibilities with set managed and setVisible, but still I have empty cells in my Listview. I expected an complete empty ListView.
What am I doing wrong?

```
    thumbSlider.setCellFactory(e -> {
        return new ListCell<Thumbnail>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Thumbnail item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null) {
                    setGraphic(item);
                    //managedProperty().bind(toggleGood.selectedProperty());
                    item.setVisible(false);
                    setVisible(false);
                    setManaged(false);
                    item.setManaged(false);
                }
            }

        };
    });
```

Comment: a) I'm not sure `ListView` even considers the `managed` property b) you need to take care of the case where the cell becomes empty c) The viewport of `ListView` is always filled with cells, whether there are enough items to fill them or not... Your best option for not showing some items at all would probably be to use a `FilteredList` with a predicate that filters out items you don't want to show as items list instead of directly using the current data.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: don't use nodes as data